# Is it illegal for an employer to send the W-2 statement of the employee to an accountant (contractor) from a third-party firm?

Tags: united-states, accounting

Is it illegal for an employer to send the employees' W-2 statements (of the employee without their permission) to the accountant (who is a third-party contractor) for the purposes of making the accountant having an easier time with reconciling the books?

Comment: would this accountant be hired by the employer? by the employee? by some third party?

Comment: Obviously some people in the company have to have access to the W-2 and the associated data (to produce the form, to audit the records, etc).  Why should an accountant not be included?

Comment: third party contractor

Comment: There is an important detail that I would add to the question. A lot of accounting firms have outsourced branches in countries like India where privacy laws are weak or not enforced at all. What would the situation be in theis case? When the W-2 is sent abroad where there is no duty of confidentiality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The employer may provide salary information, including a W-2, about an employee to an accountant, whether that accountant is also an employee of the employer, or an independent contractor hired by the employer. Normally a contract (or a company policy) will impose a duty of confidentiality on the accountant. If no such duty is explicitly imposed, there is quite likely an implied duty of confidentiality.